# Change validation definitions at runtime / Register ClientValidatorCache implementation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

**Goal:**
I want to chanage validation definitions at runtime. For example: mark a property as required.

**ModelMetaDataProvider:**

You have to bypass the caching mechanism from DefaultModelMetaProvier as descriped here:
[Getting IMetadataDetailsProviders to Run More than Once in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296817/getting-imetadatadetailsproviders-to-run-more-than-once-in-asp-net-core/47345236#47345236)

=> **Perfect, serverside validation works!** *(You can redefine the ValidationMetadata.IsRequired flag)*

But wait, what's about the **client-validation** (rendered attributes from unobrustive validation like data-required ...)? It get also cached by the *ClientValidatorCache* implementation. *(This class doesn't have virutal methods or a defined interface)*

So I created a class inherited from *DefaultValidationHtmlAttributeProvider* and override the method *AddValidationAttributes*. The new implementation call my *CustomClientValidatorCache*  with an implementation which doesn't respect the cache.

That's very ugly and there must be a much better way to accomplish that.

**So the final questions is:**

-> How I can register my own implementation for ClientValidatorCache

or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

---

(I created a Test-Repo where you can see my current bad 'solution'):
https://github.com/orphisAG/DynamicValidationTest/tree/master/DynamicValidationTest

---

**References:**

[ClientValidatorCache](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Validation/ClientValidatorCache.cs)

[DefaultValidationHtmlAttributeProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/DefaultValidationHtmlAttributeProvider.cs)

(edit: Add-References)

---

Another Try:

Create a ClientModelValidatorProvider *(IClientModelValidatorProvider)* and set IsReusable to false.

Result:

It work's only if you change ValidationMetaData from **initial existing Validator**. Because *ClientValidatorCache* will return the cached initial result ;).

Comment: It is not intended that values are changed in the validation. The mechanism does not support this either.
If you have dependent validations, use ex. FluentValidation to process complex rules.